# Getting RAM Usage of screen process

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to get the ram usage of a process.

I tried to do it with cat /proc/PID/status, but the VMSize memory usage isnt correct.
So i search for the process(ps aux | grep 25565) and got this result:

```
scmain    4754  0.0  0.0  28708  2860 ?        Ss   17:24   0:00 SCREEN -dmS sc_gs_2 java -Xms6144M -Xmx6144M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar server.jar --host 94.23.61.133 --port 25565
scmain    4755  3.7  2.1 10020484 707760 pts/41 Ssl+ 17:24   1:11 java -Xms6144M -Xmx6144M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar server.jar --host 94.23.61.133 --port 25565
scmain   16570  0.0  0.0  15748  1012 pts/40   S+   17:56   0:00 grep --color=auto 25565
```

scmain    4755  3.7  2.1 10020484 707760
This is the correct Ram and Cpu usage, but want to get the information on a easier/clean way, so that i can easier parse the output in php.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the individual columns from a row using awk:

```
ps aux | grep server.jar | head -1 | awk '{ print $5 }'
```